# How to dismiss alert in Firefox WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

In Chrome extension, I can dismiss `alert()` using `chrome.debugger` API:

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(tabId, "Page.handleJavaScriptDialog", params, function () {});
```

But Firefox WebExtensions does not support `chrome.debugger` currently, as said in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#Planned_APIs).

> **Document Reference:**
>
> **Planned APIs**
>
> We don't support the following APIs, but plan to, soon:
>
> - debugger

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What sort of dialog? Typically if you want in-page UI you inject it into the page (or open a new page) and 'chrome' ui, like a pop-up you can populate from your buttons is supported by the api

Comment: Define "handle". You probably can override the native functions.

Comment: @DanielHerr For example, I want to accept an alert in extension.

Comment: How? Async or sync? Based on user settings or input?

Comment: @DanielHerr Both are acceptable.

Comment: Then yes, you should be able to add a content script which inserts an inline script to overwrite the alert function.

Comment: Alternately, you could pop open a window and have it act like an alert.

Comment: Please describe in more detail *exact* what you are wanting, what your requirements are, etc.

Comment: So, basically, you want to programmatically make the `alert()` go away )effectively, programmatically click OK). in other words, you want to dismiss the dialog. Is that correct?  If so, how was the alert generated? A normal page script? From an extension?

Comment: @Makyen Yes. The alert is generated by user operation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by generated by user operation. User operation does not generate alerts, just by themselves (please show screenshot of what you are talking about). Something the user does may trigger the JavaScript on the page to execute `alert()`, but that is not the same thing. You need to specify **exactly** how the alert is generated. Is it from your own extension code? Is it from a web page's code? Do you want the user to be able to see and read the alert? Is is acceptable that the alert is never displayed at all?

Comment: I don't believe it is currently possible in a WebExtensions based add-on to dismiss an already existing alert. You would need to do one of: prevent the alert from ever being displayed, create a [WebExtension experiment](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), wait for the `debugger` API to be supported, or use a different extension type. Depending on exactly what you are needing, it might be viable to override the `alert()` function prior to the alert being displayed.

Comment: @Makyen Alert is generated in web page's code (not from my extension code). I read your link about WebExtension experiment. Seems it provides wrappers for XPCOM APIs, right? Do you happen to know which XPCOM API can be used to dismiss alert? I saw the [XPCOM API list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface), but didn't find anything related.

Comment: WebExtension experiments give you access to the entirety of what legacy Firefox add-ons can do. While I'd probably glance through the XPCOM APIs to see if there is something directly appropriate (I don't know one off the top of my head), what I'd try first would be directly manipulating the XUL DOM of the Firefox browser window (a DOM that includes the entirety of the browser UI, not just web page content). The alert modal appears to be inside a `<tabmodalprompt>` within the structure for the tab. From that element, find the OK button and just send a `click` event (a trusted event, if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible to dismiss an alert in WebExtensions.

See [this thread at BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323098).